# Are there any R code examples for estimating the state space vector in this case?

Tags: r, kalman-filter, state-space-models

I couldn't make sure Whether the model I'm using is a local level model with multiplicative components (state vector $\times$ regressor vector) or a linear gaussian state-space model. And couldn't find any example for R code in this case. Are there any?

[image]